# Encode/decode issues with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, decode, encode

I have the following dict. When I print out the values using beautiful soup text it prints to the screen correctly, but when I store it in a dict I get encoding issues. Wondering what I should be doing when storing the value. I tried .encode

```
{'location': 'Century College.', 'instructor': 'Forsman,\xa0Deanna', 'time': 'na\xa0-\xa0na', 'subject': 'HIST', 'id': '001538', 'seats remaning': '7', 'delivery method': 'Completely Online-Asynchronous', 'days': 'n/a', 'number': '1032', 'offered through': 'Century College.', 'credits': '4.0', 'size': 'Open', 'status': 'Off-Campus Credit.', 'dates': '08/27\xa0-\xa012/20', 'title': 'U.S. History II (Online)', 'building/room': 'Online Classes ONLINE', 'sec': '70', 'end date': '12/20/2018', 'enrolled': '27', 'start date': '8/27/2018'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try converting your object to a string first before converting to a Python `dict` object. One way you can do this is via `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

# replace with some_string = str(my_beautiful_soup_object)
some_string = str({'location': 'Century College.', 'instructor': 'Forsman,\xa0Deanna', 'time': 'na\xa0-\xa0na', 'subject': 'HIST', 'id': '001538', 'seats remaning': '7', 'delivery method': 'Completely Online-Asynchronous', 'days': 'n/a', 'number': '1032', 'offered through': 'Century College.', 'credits': '4.0', 'size': 'Open', 'status': 'Off-Campus Credit.', 'dates': '08/27\xa0-\xa012/20', 'title': 'U.S. History II (Online)', 'building/room': 'Online Classes ONLINE', 'sec': '70', 'end date': '12/20/2018', 'enrolled': '27', 'start date': '8/27/2018'})

d = literal_eval(str(some_string))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up encoding and decoding the string before putting it into the dict value.

```
.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()
```